# Time complexity of groupby in pandas with reset index

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I'm running a loop through groupby object.

```
d2_groupby = data.groupby(['A','B','C'])
def func(pattern):
    return #some indices of pattern dataframe

#first loop
for key,pattern in d2_groupby:
    func(pattern)
#second loop
for key,pattern in d2_groupby:
    func(pattern.reset_index(drop=True)
```

In above two loops, why the second loop is much faster than the first loop? The second loop is ~30 times faster.
If I want to use the first type of loop what will be the best way to write it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the function returns indices? where are you storing/printing them

Comment: And I have a feeling this is related to `drop=True`

Comment: It is completely dependant on what the func does, I imagine!

Comment: yes, it returns indices and then I'm printing it. The function just returns the indices of a row which satisfy certain conditions.

Comment: @R.K. The point here is that you are binning the index entirely in the second loop, so without seeing exactly the code in func we can't help determine why it is much faster.